# Help me navigate the dongle/dock situation please!

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

### Greetings!

---

I was recently issued a 2017 15' MBP for work, and I want to purchase accessories such that I can hook-up my home workspace to it. I thought I had the situation figured out, but as I hovered on the "checkout" button on amazon, I found a review stating my use case would not work.

---

#### The setup:

My home workspace consists of two Dell U2417H monitors. They are each currently hooked up via DP -> Mini DP to my 2015 MBP (personal). They support HDMI.

#### The ask:

Without making my monitors incompatible with my 2015, I would like to be able to use one USB-C connection on my 2017 to drive both 1080P displays and charge.

#### The failed idea:

I figured I could use the HDMI ports on my Dell monitors, hook them up to a dongle/dock and be done with it. But I can't seem to find any dongle with two HDMI outs. I found the Dell WD15 had one HDMI and one Mini DP, but evidently even using a `HDMI -> mini DP` and `HDMI -> HDMI` connectors I would only be able to mirror the two external displays.

---

What is the solution here? Two docks/docks seems inevitable. Do you have recommendations?

*Thank You,*
*Salomon*

Comment: [MST](https://blog.startech.com/post/connecting-multiple-monitors-multi-stream-transport-and-what-it-means-for-you/) exists exactly for this use case, but macOS's drivers still don't support hubs properly (despite the hardware having support; if you boot into Windows it works fine.) My testing setup consisted of a [USB-C to Mini DP adapter](https://www.amazon.com/UPTab-USB-C-DisplayPort-Adapter-Silver/dp/B01N4FQNYW/), this [MST hub](https://www.accellcables.com/products/ultraav-mini-displayport-1-2-mst-multi-display-hub), and two 27" 2009 iMacs in Target Display Mode.

Comment: The solution is to use two Thunderbolt ports, there's not enough DisplayPort bandwidth on a single port to drive dual monitors.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an external GPU driven by thunderbolt 3 if you want to output two HDMI signals from one usb-c port. (Something like this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B075RTTFDJ/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1512722145&sr=8-9&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=external+gpu+thunderbolt+3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075RTTFDJ))

If you just want to have a mirror from one to another, I think you can just use some HDMI doubler but I Donny think you will keep the same image quality (https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s?k=hdmi+doubler)

The best, easiest, and cheaper way to do what you want is just to use two ports as HDMI output on your Mac.

Comment: Gotta say, eGPU is a pretty godawful solution :/